# Open PowerShell script as ComObject

Tags: powershell

From a PS1 I am trying to open a new Powershell window running a certain script; I am trying to open it as a COM object so that I can use SendKeys with it.

I tried this,

`$newshell = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell;`

But this doesn't visibly do anything.

I tried making it visible with,

`$newshell.Visible = $true`, this throws an error that `visible` is not a property of `newshell`.

It works with other applications like Excel.

Thank you! I am new to Powershell.

Comment: you might want to look at this. https://superuser.com/questions/1249976/sendkeys-method-in-powershell

Comment: Check `$newshell | Get-Member -MemberType Properties`.